# Calculate $\int_\lambda \text{cosh}^4(z) \text{d}z$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Given the curve $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ where $\lambda_1$ is parametrized as $t+i(e^t-1)$ for $0\leq t \leq 2$ and $\lambda_2$ is parametrized as $2-t+i((e^2-1)(1-t)-t)$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$. This means that the curve $\lambda$ goes from $0$ to $1-i$.

Now I am asked to calculate $\int_\lambda \text{cosh}^4(z) \text{d}z$. Since $\text{cosh}^4(z)$ has a holomorphic primitive function: $$\int_\lambda \text{cosh}^4(z) \text{d}z=\int_\sigma \text{cosh}^4(z) \text{d}z$$

Where $\sigma$ is the curve that goes from $0$ to $1-i$. Computing I have $$\int_\sigma \text{cosh}^4(z) \text{d}z=\int_0^1 \text{cosh}^4(-x)\text{d}x=\dfrac{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{4x}}{4}+2\mathrm{e}^{2x}-2\mathrm{e}^{-2x}-\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-4x}}{4}+6x}{16}$$

Is this correct? If not, what is the correct answer?

Comment: You wrote that $\sigma$ “is the curve that goes from $0$ to $1−i$”. Which curve is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that $\cosh^4$ is holomorphic, so integrating along the open curve $\lambda$ leads to the same result as integrating along the *straight line* between the two endpoints of $\lambda$. However, your last equation makes no sense to me, because the definite integral you wrote cannot depend on $x$ (whatever that variable indicates), it should be a complex number. Here are a few hints toward the correct result:

- What are the endpoints $z_1,z_2$ of $\lambda$? (I'm not entirely sure $1-i$ is the second endpoint...)
- Let $[0,1] \ni t \mapsto \sigma(t) = z_1 t + z_2(1-t)$ be an appropriate parametrization (make sure to select the right orientation!) of the segment between $z_1$ and $z_2$, and use the formula
  $$\int_{z \in \lambda} f(z) dz = \int_0^1 f(\sigma(t)) \sigma'(t) dt $$
  to transform the complex integral into a real integral.

This should set you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry I made a typo. it is $-t$ instead of $+t$, so the endpoint is $1-i$.